# Live/scrolling chart for serial data in Powershell

Tags: powershell, serial-port

I would like to use Powershell to create a scrolling chart with input data from a Serial Port. There are programs for these but the device outputs values in scientific notation (E.g. +6.435345E6) and so needs to be parsed first. I have managed this but am trying to figure out how to make a live/scrolling chart with the data. Can anyone please advise or provide some examples?

Comment: Provide examples of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start - this script prints a value and plots a `+` at a screen position that's proportional to the range of values encountered. 
Replace `Get-Random -Maximum $Width` with whatever code you used to retrieve the numbers from the serial port.

```
$PollingInterval = 1000
$Width = 50
$Min = Get-Random -Maximum $Width #seed the minimum
Do{
    $value = Get-Random -Maximum $Width   
    $Max = [math]::Max($Max,$Value)
    $Min = [math]::Min($Min,$Value)
    $Range = $Max - $Min
    $Offset = If($Range -eq 0){0}Else{(($Value - $Min)/$Range) * $Width}
    Write-Host ("{0,5}{1}+" -f $Value,([string]' ' * $Offset))
    Sleep -Milliseconds $PollingInterval
}While ($true)
```

Comment: Thanks - I understand most of the code but can you help explain what the Write-Host line does please?

Comment: The [format string](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) `{0,5}{1}+` means the `$Value` should show, right aligned to 5 spaces, then `$Offset` spaces should appear before the '+'  sign.  In Powershell you can multiply a string times an integer to have it repeat that many times.

Comment: OK. Got it. So '{0,5}{1}+' means that we have 1) A placeholder {0} with 5 spaces width, 2) A placeholder {1}, and 3) A '+' symbol. the '-f' flag then replaces the placeholder {0} with $Value, and {1} with a space multiplied by $Offset, right?

Comment: Correct. You might want to experiment with changing `{0,5}` to `{0:n2}` depending on how many digits after the decimal are significant in your output. `'{0:n2}' -F 6.435345E6` produces output: `6,435,345.00`

Comment: Thanks again. I made some changes and the ASCII display works wonderfully for my/our needs. Write-Host ("({0,9})|{1}|{2}+{3}|{4}" -f $Value,$Min,([string]' ' * $Offset),([string]' ' * $OffsetRight),$Max). I used [math]::Round to control the display decimals instead of {0:n2} - would you suggest otherwise.